# Truffle event test: How to 'fake' values for event integration test

Tags: javascript, logic, ethereum, truffle

While being in a project using Ethereum, I ran into a new problem with truffle emitted event test, below is the description:

I have a contract function which finally emits an event name **purchaseEvent**.
My contract looks like:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract EventContract {
  address public owner;
  uint constant price = 1000000000

  event purchaseEvent(string name, uint number, uint total);

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function purchase(string memory name, uint number) public{
    emit purchaseEvent(name, number, number*price);
  }
}
```

In truffle test, I made truffle listen to the event (assume that I have contract address before):
    mainContract = create contract using EventContract Artifacts

```
let instance = Contract({
  abi: Artifact.abi,
  bytecode: Artifact.bytecode
})
let provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:7777')
instance.setProvider(provider)
eventContract = await instance.at(mainContract.address)
await eventContract.purchaseEvent({}, async(err, event)=>{
     handleEvent(event.returnValues)
})
```

My handleEvent function is:

```
function handleEvent(event){
     console.log('Bill:', event.total)
     // do calculation with value of 'total' 
}
```

It (the event handler) works fine when I make a call to purchase with 
contractInstance.purchase('tony', 5)

Now I have a problem about testing: **How could I 'fake' the 'price' value (or the 'total' result) for test purpose**

**My idea**
I then have some options:

1. Create an extra contract named 'TestEvent' where price = ANOTHER value for testing. It will be ok, but writing another contract could mess up the project.
2. (What I've done) Write a small scope of code to modify 'handleEvent' behavior:

```
    function handleEvent(event){
             if (process.env.status == 'test') event.total = 50 // assign a constant for testing
             console.log('Bill:', event.total)
             // do calculation with value of 'total' 
    }
```

But it is likely to mess the function logic, isn't it?

Could you please share your experience of doing such test? Many many thanks

Comment: There's the waffle library that allows to create mocks.

Comment: Wow, many thanks. Let me check it out